# Overload is operator in python

Tags: python, operator-overloading

I have a class. I'd like to use statement `MyClass() is None` and get `True`.

I assume I can overload some method to change `is` operator result.
I see it somehow like this:

```
class MyClass:
    ...(self, other):
        if other is None:
            return True
        return id(self) == id(other)

print(MyClass() is None)
```

Is there actually any way to implement it?

Comment: "I'd like to use statement `MyClass() is None` and get `True`." This will never happen. You cannot change the way identity works, and you **absolutely shouldn't' to begin with**.

Comment: Note that while you can't override the `id()` and thus effect `is`, You can alter the `hash()` and that might be leveraged to do `hash(MyClass()) == hash(None)`

Comment: @JonSG but how would that be useful?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm not sure how it would be, but I think it is kind of similar to what the OP wants with `MyClass() is None` which also does not make sense to me.

Comment: From [Identity comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not), `is` is defined strictly as an identity test: _x is y is true if and only if x and y are the same object_. Since it can't be anything other than identity, it isn't a _rich comparison operator_ and cannot be overloaded.

Comment: There is a case where `MyClass() is None` makes sense. If you write a custom `__new__` method that can return `None`, `MyClass()` can indeed be `None`. But that doesn't seem to be what you are after here.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible -- let alone desirable -- to change the way the `is` operator works in Python (barring changing the CPython source code itself).

`is` is for identity, *always*. And it *should* stay that way.